# Set SSIS database package path

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I am trying to execute a SSIS package located in a database programatically.

I am using this API:

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
```

I have an image describing the path (in database) to package but I cannot figure out how to set the *packagePath* property properly in the *LoadFromSqlServer* method.

Here is the image describing my package path in database:

[image]

Comment: Good question and one I don't have an answer to, yet. `LoadFromSqlServer` is going to access packages in the msdb.dbo.sysssispackages table. For SQL Server 2012, packages are now stored in the dedicated SSISDB catalog. Based on the documentation, we have [LoadFromSqlServer2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application.loadfromsqlserver2.aspx) but the first line there states "is not intended to be used directly from your code". Are you trying to listen to the events and such or would just starting the package be sufficient for you needs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices. For me, it does not show up in the SQL Server folders and I could only find it in the GAC.

`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll`

There's also a dependency from that assembly to

`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll`

```vb
Sub Main()
    '
    ' Do not fault me for my poor VB skills nor my lack of error handling
    ' This is bare bones code adapted from 
    ' http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/11/17/ssis-and-powershell-in-sql-server-2012.aspx

    Dim folderName As String
    Dim projectName As String
    Dim serverName As String
    Dim packageName As String
    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim use32BitRuntime As Boolean
    Dim executionId As Integer

    Dim integrationServices As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices
    Dim catalog As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.Catalog
    Dim catalogFolder As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder
    Dim package As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo

    ' Dimensions in your example
    folderName = "SSISHackAndSlash"
    ' dimCalendar in your example
    projectName = "SSISHackAndSlash2012"
    serverName = "localhost\dev2012"

    ' dimCalendar in your example (no file extension)
    packageName = "TokenTest.dtsx"
    connectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;", serverName)

    integrationServices = New Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
    ' There is only one option for an SSIS catalog name as of this posting
    catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs("SSISDB")

    ' Find the catalog folder. Dimensions in your example
    catalogFolder = catalog.Folders(folderName)

    ' Find the package in the project folder
    package = catalogFolder.Projects(projectName).Packages(packageName)

    ' Run the package. The second parameter is for environment variables
    executionId = package.Execute(use32BitRuntime, Nothing)

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to explore this code? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks, I will get back to you soon. Just need to get hold of these dll:s.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am still searching for the dll: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll - not sure why I cannot see it among the files.

Comment: Found the file and this works. Do you know the difference between SSISDB and other SSIS execution?

Comment: Wat is path we need to give to execute package in ssisdb??

Answer (score 2):

In addition to billinkc [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510415/1970317).

Here is the C# version of the code:

```
string folderName = "name";
string projectName = "name";
string serverName = "localhost";
string packageName = "name";
string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;", serverName);

var integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(newSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString));
var catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"];
var catalogFolder = catalog.Folders[folderName];

var package = catalogFolder.Projects[projectName].Packages[packageName];

long execId = package.Execute(false, null);
```

In my case I had to add 4 dlls:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
```

All the dependencies can be found `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the package location deployed in SQL server.

1. Open SSMS.
2. Connect to Integration Services.
3. Go to View and Click "Object Explorer Details".
4. Now you select your package to know the package path in SQL server.
   Take a look at the screenshot below.

Ignore the server name because it will be parameter for the `LoadFromSqlServer` method.

So package path should be : \Stored Package\MSDB\Data Collector\PerfCountersUpload.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but it seems to be slightly different when not in MSDB but in "Integration Services Catalogs".

Comment: To describe the relation between MSDB and Integration Services Dialog I have this image [link](http://neteject.com/download/ssis.png)