# How do I run an SSIS package in SqlServer 2012 using vs2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2012

#### Setup

I have a vs2010 SSIS package that I can run from visual studio.  I have deployed it to my local 2012 server, and I can also execute that package from SSMS.  In SSMS, I see the package here:

> \Integration Services Catalogs\SSISDB\DAT_Load\Projects\UploadSYS.dtsx

Note: vs2010 does not give me an option to deploy a package anywhere but in a server, and then only in Integration Services Catalogs.  Once in there, the MSDB database does *not* have an entry in the sysssispackages table.

Previously, it was adequate to bring up SSMS and run the package from there(right-click & execute).  Now, I have to execute this from a C# web application.  Furthermore, I need to trap progress messages and such through events.

#### Effort

I was able to determine how to set up the event trapping and I got myself to the point where I should have been able to execute the package from code:

```
    public DTSExecResult ExecutePackage(string packageName, HttpContextBase context)
    {
        string ppath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[packageName + "Package"];
        string pserv = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[packageName + "Server"];
        string puser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[packageName + "User"];
        string ppass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[packageName + "Pwd"];
        _context = context;
        _pkgLocation = "";
        _app = new Application();
        _pkg = _app.LoadFromSqlServer(ppath, pserv, puser, ppass, _SSISEvents);
        _pkgResults = _pkg.Execute(_connections, _variables, _SSISEvents, _log, null);
        return _pkgResults;
    }
```

#### Problem

I cannot locate the package.  When I reach the LoadFromSqlServer statement, I receive an error that says:

> Cannot find folder "\Integration Services Catalogs\SSISDB\DAT_Load\Projects\UploadSYS.dtsx"

The same thing happens for variations in the path (variable = ppath):

- \Integration Services Catalogs\SSISDB\DAT_Load\Projects\UploadSYS.dtsx
- \SSISDB\DAT_Load\Projects\UploadSYS.dtsx
- \DAT_Load\Projects\UploadSYS.dtsx
- etc.

Running this from the command line or a stored procedure is not an option.

So, can anyone tell what I am missing here?  Does the Application object need to initialize something?  Is this even possible?

Comment: There is something that I think I am missing.  I set a breakpoint and ran the FolderExistsOnSqlServer command to see which folders were actually there.  Surprise!  The folders under Integration Services Catalogs are not the locations for FolderExistsOnSqlServer.  I can only assume that the same is true for all fo the DTS methods.  Now, how do I get my package from ISC into MSDB?

Comment: MSDB = package deployment model. SSISDB = project deployment model. [SSIS Organization](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46130/ssis-organization) The way in which you interact with them, once deployed, is different. Ultimately, your question is: how do I programmatically run an SSIS package in the project deployment model via C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking another bite at the problem but see  [Set SSIS database package path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475119/set-ssis-database-package-path) and [SSIS Organization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46130/ssis-organization) for background reading.

Until SSIS 2012, if packages were deployed to SQL Server, they lived in the msdb. The .NET API for interacting with them was the same across versions.

With the 2012 release of SSIS, we have two different deployment models. Package deployment, which is the "classic" model is alive and fully supported. The same code for running a package on 2005 will work for 2012 package deployment model projects. This is the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) Namespace

Your code is attempting to load a 2012 solution built using the "project deployment model" with the "package deployment model" API. This is the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.aspx) Namespace and the two don't mix.

Your options are to switch your project back to the Package deployment model or update your code. In the first linked question, I provided the VB.NET implementation for running an SSIS package in the SSISDB catalog. There is *some* way of running a .ispac file because I see the option in `dtexec` but I'm not seeing the specific method. This is mechanism VS/SSDT uses when it runs the packages locally.

Comment: I understand.  I had earlier stumbled upon the Integration Services DLLs, but I was confused about that vs the Dts.Runtime api.  And, since my reputation is below 15, I can't vote your answer up as it deserves.  :)

Comment: No worries. If this solves your problem, you can click the check mark and that'll mark the question as resolved (and you'll earn 2 rep). Otherwise, let me know what else I can do to improve this answer.

Comment: So, I was able to translate the VB code into my C# app.  Many thanks for that @billinkc.  Unfortunately, I cannot see how I can trap the events fired from the package.  More research must be done here.  If this is impossible from the IntegrationServices api, then I need to go back to the Dts api and create a deployed package.  Nonetheless, you have answered the question and gave me a path to use if I must ignore events.  Gosh darn that SSIS...