# In SSIS how to load the package inside Script Task c# code

Tags: ssis

In SSIS Script task I am able to load the package by providing the full path as following, but on the server I don't know the exact path after deployment, Is there any way to load the package and its configuration file.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
        Package package = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\tfs01\AURA\DB\Main\Src\ReportSolution\AURA_ETL\AURA_ETL\DTS_PatientModel.dtsx", null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, the documentation is your friend.

Instead of calling [LoadPackage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application.loadpackage.aspx), you need to use [LoadFromSqlServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application.loadfromsqlserver.aspx). LoadPackage pulls from disk, LoadFromSqlServer talks to the msdb.

Note that if you are working with the 2012 project deployment, it's an [entirely different mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064703/how-do-i-run-an-ssis-package-in-sqlserver-2012-using-vs2010/18072045#18072045).